# Volume for domain is already created. Please run 'vagrant destroy' first

Tags: vagrant, libvirt

I'm trying to create a vagrant vm with vagrant up and libvirt as provider. But when i'm running the command i'm getting this error = "Volume for domain is already created. Please run 'vagrant destroy' first." But i can't find any domains when i'm running 'virsh list -all' .

Any suggestions?